# Axon Testing: Missing Context

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, axon

In an Axon-SpringBoot App I have an aggregate that uses an injected DAO in some of its command handlers.

For instance:

```
@Aggregate
class MyAggregate {

    @CommandHandler
    public MyAggregate (CreateMyAggregateCommand command, @Autowired MyAggregateDao dao) {

          final SomeProperty = command.getSomePoprtery();

          if (dao.findBySomeProperty(someProperty) == null) {
               AggregateLifeCycle.apply(
                     new MyAggregateCreatedEvent(command.getIdentifier(),
                                                 someProperty);
          } else {
               // Don't create, already exits with some property
               // report ...
          }
    }

}
```

A standard test like

```
@Test
void creationSucceeds () {

    aggregateTestFixture = new AggregateTestFixture<>(MyAggregate.class);

    final CreateMyAggregateCommand command = new CreateMyAggregateCommand(...);
    final MyAggregateCreatedEvent = new MyAggregateCreatedEvent(...);

    aggregateTestFixture
            .givenNoPriorActivity()
            .when(command)
            .expectEvents(event);

}
```

fails with:

```
org.axonframework.test.FixtureExecutionException: No resource of type 
[com.xmpl.MyAggregateDao] has been registered. It is required 
for one of the handlers being executed.
```

How can I provide a test implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution 1: Mocking

Since this is about unit testing and my question involves database calls (external service), mocking seems applicable as long as testing is about isolated aggregate behavior only.

```
@Test
void creationSucceeds () {

    aggregateTestFixture = new AggregateTestFixture<>(MyAggregate.class);
    aggregateTestFixture.registerInjectableResource(
          Mockito.mock(MyAggregateDao.class));

}
```

### Solution 2: Real Injection (jUnit 5)

This one works for me:

1. Get small library for Spring jUnit5 testing support from [this github repo](https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5)
2. Annotate test classes:

   ```
   @SpringBootTest(classes = {SpringTestConfig.class}) 
   @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
   public class MyAggregateTest {

       // ...        

   }
   ```
3. Place application.properties in src/test/resources
4. Write Spring Test Configuration which starts a fully functioning Spring container:

   ```
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   public class SpringTestConfig {

        // Set up whatever you need

        @Bean
        @Autowired
        MyAggregateDao myDao (DataSource dataSource) {

            // ...
        }


        @Bean
        @Autowired
        EventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine () {

            return new InMemoryEventStorageEngine();

        }

   }
   ```
5. Inject directly into your tests, configure `AggregateTestFixture`

   ```
   private AggregateTestFixture<MyAggregate> aggregateTestFixture;

   @Autowired
   private MyAggregateDao myDao;

   @BeforeEach
   void beforeEach () {

       aggregateTestFixture = new AggregateTestFixture<>(MyAggregate.class);

       // We still need to register resources manually
       aggregateTestFixture.registerInjectableResource(myDao);

   }
   ```

### With jUnit 4

Setting up a test configuration that starts a Spring container with jUnit 4 is a bit different but there's enough documentation out there. Start [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)